# changing gridview row color on condition within button click function

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a loop that goes through my gridview and counts the instances where gender field is set to 'M' when a button is clicked.
I would like to also change that color of that row with the same condition, i.e. if the gender is 'M'.

Here is my loop so far and any help would be very appreciated!

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int intfemdelegates = 0;

    foreach(GridViewRow oItem in GridView1.Rows) 
    {
        if (oItem.Cells[6].Text.Contains('F'))
        {
            intfemdelegates = intfemdelegates + 1;
            GridView1.RowStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
        Label2.Text = Convert.ToString(intfemdelegates);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the issue? Is something not working?

Comment: well i only want to change to row color where the gender is set to 'm' and this code changes all the rows to red regardless of the condition.

Comment: When the condition is true, you are changing the row style of the entire GridView to red, not just a specific row.

Answer (score 0):

This code may be useful... good luck!

```
int intfemdelegates = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; i++)
{
    if (dataGridView1[1, i].Value.ToString() == "F")
    {
        intfemdelegates = intfemdelegates + 1;
        dataGridView1[1, i].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Gray;
    }
}
lblcount.Text = intfemdelegates.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are changing RowColor on whole Grid1. change to this

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  {
  int intfemdelegates = 0;

    foreach(GridViewRow oItem in GridView1.Rows) {
     if (oItem.Cells[6].Text.Contains('F')) {
       intfemdelegates = intfemdelegates + 1;
       oItem.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
 }

   Label2.Text = Convert.ToString(intfemdelegates);

  }
```